# How does autojump change the current working directory?

Tags: bash

[autojump](https://github.com/wting/autojump) works by maintaining a database of the directories you use the most from the command line. Then you can `cd` to directories via shortcuts, e.g. to jump to a directory that contains "foo", I can just call `j foo` instead of `cd /full/path/to/foo`.

```bash
$ pwd
/some/directory
$ j foo
/full/path/to/foo
```

I'm trying to understand how autojump is able to change the directory by calling `cd` inside its bash script. As far as I know, such a script is executed in a separate shell. Here's the [part](https://github.com/wting/autojump/blob/06e082c91805cb022900819b2e0881eeae780d58/bin/autojump.bash#L69) in autojump's code that calls `cd`.

For example, calling this doesn't change the directory outside of the script, so how is autojump able to achieve it?

```bash
# myscript.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd path/to/foo
```

```bash
$ pwd
/some/directory
$ ./myscript.sh
/some/directory
```

Comment: sooooo have you considered that it is _not_ a script? https://github.com/wting/autojump/blob/master/bin/autojump.bash#L56

Comment: `calling this ` You are calling a script. Not a script. It's a shell function. See the source code above. There is no _script_ file named `j`. It's a shell function. I can only advise to read a shell introduction.

Answer (score 2):

> How do zoxide and autojump change the current working directory?

Normally, with `cd`.

> As far as I know, such a script is executed in a separate shell.

So they are not scripts, they are shell functions.

> How is it able to call the function from the terminal in a way that it changed the directory in the terminal?

Like so:

```
$ cat mycdfunction.sh
mycdfunction() {
    echo "jumping to my place"
    cd tomyplace
}
$ . mycdfunction.sh
$ mycdfunction
jumping to my place
$ pwd
myplace
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint @KamilCuk. Though I still don't quite get it. How is it able to call the function from the terminal in a way that it changed the directory in the terminal? Please look at my question again, I've extended it with additional information.

Comment: @bler, clearly, installing autojump involves setting your shell up to source the file in which the function is defined during that shell's startup, thus having the function defined inside your shell already, _before_ you try to run it.